# Does GeoServer support geocoding?

Tags: geoserver, geocoding

I have used GeoServer for rendering my own maps.

Can GeoServer be used to serve geocoding / reverse geocoding requests (i.e. you put a street address and it gives you coordinates and vice versa)?

I am using non-US addresses.

Comment: For software recommendations for geocoding see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=geocoding

Comment: No it can not be used for geocoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoServer has no geocoding functionality built in. There is however a number of open source geocoders out there, this site offers a list (not sure if it's complete or up to date, just sharing as an example):
https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/geocoder

If you need the GeoCoding to happen through a OGC compliant service, wrapping in a WPS process would be possible (either writing some Java code to make it happen, or wrapping it through another open source WPS server).